# Python (PyQt), рамка вокруг виджета QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Пишу программу, которая будет показывать погоду (использую `PyQt`). У меня есть 7 `QLabel` виджетов, на которые и выводится погода.

Задача проста: сделать рамку вокруг каждого `QLabel`, так сказать, чтобы их визуально отделить друг от друга.

---

Читал на английском stackoverflow: народ предлагает ставить картинку, но, по мне, это скорее костыль. Есть ли еще какой-то вариант?

Comment: Попробовать через Qt Style Sheets нарисовать рамку

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Рамку у QLabel можно сделать при помощи [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html).

Пример кода:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QApplication)

class TestQSS(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Test QSS')

        label = QLabel('Test label', self)
        label.move(30, 30)

        label.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')

        self.resize(250,150)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

tq = TestQSS()
tq.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

[QLabel](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) наследуется от [QFrame](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qframe.html), поэтому ему самому можно указать рамку.

Если передать в метод [setFrameStyle](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qframe.html#setFrameStyle) значение [QFrame.Box](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qframe.html#Shape-enum), то у `label`'ов будет рамка.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/692bdb51d4e4273d34fa11a0a2a588259d56ea57/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/label_framed.py):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.create_label_framed('Hello'))
        layout.addWidget(self.create_label_framed('World'))
        layout.addWidget(self.create_label_framed('999'))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    @staticmethod
    def create_label_framed(text):
        label = Qt.QLabel(text)
        label.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.Box)

        return label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]